# creating component instances from array.map() and handing down functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just a quick query.

I have an array of data points and using this to create instances of a component.

The parent component that creates an array of children components also have some functions I wish to hand down to its children. Is there any way this is possible? Check the code and let me know, I am getting errors.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this)
  }
handleNext() {
    // some function that uses setState and will cause component to re render
}
render() {
    let children = someArray.map(function(elem, index) {
        return (
            <ChildComponent name = {elem.name} handDownFunc = {this.handleNext}/>
                )
    })
return (
            {children} // I want them to each be able to access and use handleNext
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: What error message did you get? Have you tried wrap the `{children}` in a `<React.Fragment>` element?

Comment: Yeah so I've tried wrapping it but its part of something bigger (I trimmed down the code for readability) , so that doesnt work. 
The error is good old - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleNext' of undefined

Comment: Where does the error come from. Does it throw from your ChildComponent

Comment: The problem is probably that `this` will not be bound in the callback passed to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description). Either try using a lambda (arrow function), or store `this` in a temporary variable and bind it to `handleNext`.

Comment: oh yeah, referring to handleNext - undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error, because using `function` keyword instead of arrow function.
For more infromation please follow this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/).
So, it will be `someArray.map(() => { return() })`

Comment: yeah, found that one out earlier. Being silly. Thank you though!